# Intent Action SEND always opens GMail

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail, send

I created a SEND Intent to send a File as export for my App. Normally I could choose a App with the chooser but without changing anything on the code, the chooser is gone and it opens every time the GMail App.

This is the chooser how it should looks like:
 [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6p7KOnEpvogMGZTSlMyMGNnVms/edit?usp=sharing)
A friend tested it for me on his phone (same like mine - Nexus 5).

Code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mContext.getFilesDir() + "/" + mContext.getString(R.string.filename)));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mContext.getString(R.string.backup_email_subject, getFormattedTime()));
shareIntent.setType("text/rtf");
mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, mContext.getString(R.string.backup_export)));
```

I restarted the Phone, deleted all data from GMail and also checked the "open always" settings, but nothing fixed it. I also removed the EXTRA_SUBJECT but it still opens GMail without showing the chooser at any time.

I hope this is not a bad bug :-)
Does anyone had this issue?

Comment: did you clear defaults of the gmail app?

Comment: None of those apps can access files in  your app's internal storage. Use `FileProvider` to serve those files to third-party apps.

Comment: you mean below the App-Info? It told me "no defaults" or something and the button to clear it is disabled

Comment: ofcourse they can access - did you see the chooser? I already did it and it worked. For example sending via mail. - you can write the files in WORLD_READABLE_MODE

Comment: i can see the chooser activity ..Verified in Nexus4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a system bug. It was fixed with Android 4.4.2